# Trying to reset a form input fiedl to blank after submit

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I have a php form with angularjs code. The initial screen looks like
[Before submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpweR.png)

Once the user submit the form I would like to blank out all fields, However the following code doesnot seem to do so for the field, but does for the button.

[after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSRq6.png)

Before 
After
the form and code is as follow, i tried blanking the email field. The button is changed so I know it going thru the angularjs code.

```
<!-- Contact Section Angularjs -->
<div id="myapp"  ng-controller="contacts_empcontroller">
<div id="contact" class="w3-container w3-padding-16" >
<h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">Contact</h3>
<form id="contact_02" >
<p><h4> If you would like to book an event or conference please contact us.</h4></p>

    <p ng-bind="msg1"></p>
    <input id="name1"   class="w3-input w3-section"    type="text" placeholder="Name"    required name="Name"    value=" "      ng-model="name1">
    <input id="email1"  class="w3-input w3-section"    type="text" placeholder="Email"   required name="Email"   value=""     ng-model="email1">
    <input id="subject1" class="w3-input w3-section"   type="text" placeholder="Subject" required name="Subject" value=""   ng-model="subject1">
    <input id="comment1" class="w3-input w3-section"   type="text" placeholder="Comment" required name="Comment" value=""   ng-model="comment1">
    <input id="token1"   class="w3-input w3-section"   type="hidden" name="token1"       value="<?php echo $token;?>" >
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section" ng-click="postData()" id="buttoncontact" >Send Message</button></p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Angularjs code

```
  if (data.success == "ip_over_2")
    {

      document.getElementById("buttoncontact").innerHTML = "Duplicate - Thanks";

      document.getElementById("email1").innerHTML = "-";

    }
```

Thanks for any help

Second form

```
<div class=" col-sm-4 ">
<div id="myapp"  ng-controller="subscribe_controller">
<h4 style="color:black;" >Subscribe To Newsletter</h4>
<form id="subscribe_01">
<h4>
    <p ng-bind="msg2"></p>
    <input id="email2"   style="color:gray;" type="text" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your Email Adddress" value="" ng-model="email2" required  ></h4>
    <input id="token2"   class="w3-input w3-section"   type="hidden" name="token2"       value="<?php echo $token;?>" >

    Enter Code: <font size="3" color="blue"><?php echo $captcha_token;?> </font>&nbsp&nbsp

    <input id="captcha"  type="text"  placeholder="Code" name="captcha" value=""  ng-model="captcha" size="10" required>
    <p><p>

    <button class="w3-button w3-black" ng-click="postData_subscribe()" id="buttoncontact_subscribe">Send To Subscribe</button></p>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementById("...").innerHTML;` just do:

```
$scope.name1 = '';
$scope.email1 = '';
$scope.subject1 = '';
$scope.comment1 = '';
```

This will update your model (`ng-model="email1"`) with the specified value, in this case a blank value (as you specified was the goal).

Comment: Perfect!  Glad to hear that helped.   Also just a general rule of thumb, you should avoid doing any type of DOM manipulation unless you're writing a directive.  Let angular handle all the DOM work for you.

Comment: Also if you wouldn't mind to accept / upvote the answer to signify its been answered :D

Comment: How would this work if i want to update to seperate angularjs forms.

Comment: Is the second form, part of the same angular controller?

Comment: I will update the answer, It was so fast, it didn't let me do it in the first 3 mintues.

Comment: no, say I want to update a second controller form with data from the first controller form.

Comment: I added the second from in the question. Let say I want to update the email address in the second from with data from the name in the first form.

Comment: Depending on how your application is structured, there are multiple ways to communicate between angular controllers.   You can use `$scope.broadcast` / `$scope.emit` to emit messages and then `$scope.on` to listen for them.   You can use services to hold data for you (these are basically just singleton objectives).  If the other controller is a child or parent you can use `$scope.$parent`.    Of all the options, I'd suggest trying to use a service, however all are valid.

Comment: Question:  Is this acting as a single page application, or is your php script reloading the page to a different view?

Comment: no it does everything inside the one load of the page. It working fine now. Thanks I just was wondering  if I could reference a form field in a second form from the first app code exactly at the spot I blank form 1 fields